# Is it possible to inject SSR with data stored in client side Quasar?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering, quasar-framework, quasar

Is it possible to inject SSR with data stored in client side?
After login i stored token and another data in **vuex** store, but i can't find this data in SSR in `window.__INITIAL_STATE__`
I'm using Vuejs and Quasar
I set `manualHydration: true,` for SSR in **quasar config **

I need SSR **INITIAL_STATE** data same as vuex store data